# Small Business with Expenses on Personal Account

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business

We have a C Corp that I am filing taxes for.

I have some expenses that are valid business expenses, that I paid for with a personal credit card.

How do I account for those?

Yes, I realize going forward I should not do that!

Comment: Reimburse yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expenses should be accounted for the same way business expenses are handled when an employee pay for something that their employer will reimburse.  (Think hotel room and food while on a business trip).  You need to fill out some sort of reimbursement form and submit the form and receipts to the business.   The company then approves the form and pays you back for the expenses.  This way business and person accounts are kept separate and there is a trail of paperwork explaining payments made by the company to yourself.

Comment: What is the business has no income yet?  Normally, the expense would be a carryover credit, but since it came from a personal account...?

Comment: It will be an expense from the business account once it pays you back.  the charges become another business expense on the business's books.